# Why is the first return in my javascript while loop undefined?

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, undefined

why is my while loop returning 'undefined' in the first loop instead of 'time'?

```js
let i = 1,
  quantity;
while (i <= 10) {
  console.log(`${txtsoobin.firstName} sang blue hour ${i} ${quantity}.`);
  i++;
  if (i == 1) {
    quantity = 'time';
  } else {
    quantity = 'times'
  }
}
```

sorry if the code looks messy i just started learning javascript

Comment: You mean the first print? If yes, this is because you didn't assign any value to `quantity`. You need to move the `if` statement before the `console.log()` so the variable is assigned before print.

Comment: Why should it write time? You haven't assigned `"time"` to the variable  yet.

Comment: Tip: It seemed messy because you didn't indent it properly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because when you declare quantity, you are not assigning any value to it, thus it is `undefined`.

During the first loop, your are logging quantity before you assign it `'time'` or `'times'`. So quantity is still undefined.
If you want it to log something else than undefined, just move it below the if/else loop, like this :

```js
let i = 1,
  quantity;
while (i <= 10) {
  i++;
  if (i === 1) {
    quantity = 'time';
  } else {
    quantity = 'times'
  }
  console.log(`${txtsoobin.firstName} sang blue hour ${i} ${quantity}.`);
}
```